# google analytics error for in page analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an old domain in which google analytics is tracking. I bought a new domain and redirect traffic from the old domain to the new domain by .htaccess file. For the new domain, I created another tracker object as well. Now when I am accessing in page analytics for both, I encountered the error below

```
Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report. [Error :20004]
```

My attempt is using the auto linker to link up. But it still shows the error

```
ga('linker:autolink', ['old domain'],true);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In Admin > Property Settings, is the Default URL your new domain (without any redirects)?

Answer (score 0):

@SamPerry is correct!

You will need to check your property setting. Go to View Settings and make sure that your "Website's URL" is set to the new domain.